# Returning a copy with overloaded operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class `Foo` for which I've overloaded the + operator as follows:

```
Foo Foo::operator+(const Bar &b)
{
    Foo copy = (*this);
    if (someCondition) return copy;
    //snip
}
```

To me, this looks reasonable.  However, whenever I am returning copy, Visual Studio alerts me of an error which 'may be due to a corruption of the heap'.  Is there something wrong with what I've done?

edit: updating with more info.

**The error message:**

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in
>   sample.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the
>   heap, which indicates a bug in
>   sample.exe or any of the DLLs it has
>   loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user
>   pressing F12 while sample.exe has
>   focus.
>
> The output window may have more
>   diagnostic information.

**The copy constructor:**

```
Foo::Foo(const Foo&p)
{
    some_pointer = p.get_some_pointer();
    some_value = p.get_some_value();
}
```

**The code it breaks to:**

```
//within dbgheap.c
    extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(
            const void * pUserData
            )
    {
            if (!pUserData)
                return FALSE;

            if (!_CrtIsValidPointer(pHdr(pUserData), sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader), FALSE))
                return FALSE;

            return HeapValidate( _crtheap, 0, pHdr(pUserData) );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the copy constructor of `Foo`?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y @metdos I have updated with more info

Comment: @socks: It looks like your copy constructor is performing a flat copy, in which case it is superfluous. Does the destructor of `Foo` release any resources?

Comment: Did you happen to overload the assignment operator to do something different than your copy constructor?

Comment: If you `delete some_pointer` in the destructor, that will be a problem. Also how about your assignment operator? I think `Foo copy = (*this);` is an assignment rather than copy.

Comment: @sad_man, @Andrew: `Foo copy = (*this)` invokes the copy constructor.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Even if the assignment operator is written explicitly?

Comment: @sad_man : Yes, it invokes copy constructor even if the (copy) assignment operator is overloaded explicitly.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y, @Mahesh: Oh I see now. Thanks. @socks: What does some_pointer point to?

Comment: Please post the code that is using operator+ and giving you the error.

Comment: @sad_man it points to another Foo object

Comment: Go up the call stack when you crash until you find your own code in the call stack. Post *that* code.

Answer (score 3):

That type of error is usually associated with multiple deletions (or frees) of the same pointer, or with some more obscure situations (acquiring from one heap and releasing to a different heap, but that is probably not the case here).

The first thing I would do is look a the destructors and check that you are not shallow copying and doubly deleting. For example with the following code:

```
// buggy!!!
struct test {
    int * data;
    test() : data( new int[5] ) {}
    ~test() { delete [] data; }
    test( test const & rhs ) : data( rhs.data ) {}
    test& operator=( test const & rhs ) {
       data = rhs.data;
    }
};
int main() {
    test t1;          // 5 ints allocated int t1.data
    test t2( t1 );    // no memory allocated, t2.data == t1.data
} // t2 out of scope: t2.~test() => delete t2.data
  // t1 out of scope: t1.~test() => delete t1.data but both are the same: double delete
```

If this is the case, you can decide whether you want to have shallow copies or make deep copies. In the second case the copy constructor (and assignment operator) should allocate their own memory, while in the second case you must ensure that the memory is not released twice.

As always with pointers, it is better to delegate resource management to external (pre-built) classes. In the case of unique ownership (and deep copies) you should probably use `std::auto_ptr` (or `std::unique_ptr` in C++0x -- or the boost variants). In the second case, using `boost::shared_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr` in C++0x) will ensure that the data is shared and only deleted once.

Comment: And if the class does not own the object the pointer points to, prefer a reference.

Comment: @Space: A preference that will effectively render the class non-assignable (which would perhaps be weird for a class with arithmetic operators)...

Comment: @visitor: Right, didn't consider that.